# How to Access Activation Functions from Saved Model .h5 without importing tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, h5py

Is the activation function for each layer stored in the .h5 file produced by model.save()? Or is it already "baked in" to the weights?

I am writing an AWS Lambda function to generate time-series predictions from multiple regression models every five minutes. Unfortunately, TensorFlow is too large of a library to be loaded into an AWS Lambda function, so I am writing my own Python code to load the saved .h5 model file and generate predictions based on the weights and input data. Here's where I'm at so far:

```
def generate_predictions(model_path, df):
    model_info = h5py.File(model_path, 'r')
    model_weights = model_info['model_weights']
    # Initialize predictions matrix with preprocessed inputs
    predictions = preprocessing.scale(df[inputs])
    layer_list = list(model_weights.keys())
    for layer in layer_list:
        weights = model_weights[layer][layer]['kernel:0'][:]
        bias = model_weights[layer][layer]['bias:0'][:]
        predictions = predictions.dot(weights)
        predictions += bias
        # How to retrieve activation function for layer?
        # predictions = activation_function(predictions)

    return predictions
```

I understand I'll probably want some kind of case/switch statement to handle the various activation functions.

Comment: What's the nature of this `activation function`?  As far as I know, `h5py` can only save/load numpy arrays (or their equivalent).  `.h5` files are for data, not code.  `h5py` file has groups and datasets.  Datasets load as arrays.  Each level can also have attributes, usually smaller arrays or strings.  If you can't find it via the `keys` it's not there.

Comment: @hpaulj - activation functions are operations performed on the layer's output, such as linear, relu, tanh, softmax, etc. [link](https://keras.io/activations/) I would have thought that they'd be stored as attributes, but they don't seem to be there.
And the activation function must be stored somewhere, otherwise you wouldn't be able to call model.predict() on a loaded model.

Comment: Without a sample file, I really can't help you.  If there's a fixed number of functions, then they might well be stored by name or code.  Looks like the configuration can also be stored as `JSON`. The functions are probably not stored in any sort of binary or executable form; rather just enough information to recreate the model.

Comment: @hpaulj - it would be fine if they are stored by name or code, I just need to know what they are. The model configuration can be stored as JSON, but the weights are not included in that format. TF seems to be able to access configuration data from the .h5 file, but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The model configuration is accessible through an attribute called "model_config" on the top group that seems to contain the full model configuration JSON that is produced by model.to_json().

```
import json
import h5py
model_info = h5py.File('model.h5', 'r')
model_config_json = json.loads(model_info.attrs['model_config'])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you save the full model with `model.save`, you can access each layer and it's activation function.

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
model = load_model('model.h5')

for l in model.layers:
  try:
    print(l.activation)
  except: # some layers don't have any activation
    pass
```

```
<function tanh at 0x7fa513b4a8c8>
<function softmax at 0x7fa513b4a510>
```

Here, for example, `softmax` is used in the last layer.

If you don't want to import tensorflow, you can also read from h5py.

```
import h5py
import json

model_info = h5py.File('model.h5', 'r')

model_config = json.loads(model_info.attrs.get('model_config').decode('utf-8'))

for k in model_config['config']['layers']:
  if 'activation' in k['config']:
      print(f"{k['class_name']}: {k['config']['activation']}")
```

```
LSTM: tanh
Dense: softmax
```

Here, last layer is a dense layer which has softmax activation.

Comment: Can you comment on if it is possible to access at least the name of the activation functions directly from the .h5 file without importing TensorFlow?

Comment: technically yes, but h5 stores binary data, it would be almost impossible to decode all the model details without loading tensorflow.

Comment: That's not necessarily true, in the code I shared in the question I'm able to efficiently access the bias and kernel for each layer. It is straightforward to do the dot product with the kernel and add the bias, but I'm having trouble locating the activation functions in the .h5 file.